# Error in SSIS package while importing data from text file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ssis

I created a package in SSIS. source is a text file and destination is MySQL.  When I am trying to run the package, I am getting the following error.

> "[ADO NET Destination [195]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.13-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Comment: post sql statement, cannot help you with sql syntax if there is no sql syntax posted

Comment: Thank you AdrianBR, I am not specifying any SQL statement in the SSIS package. I am using the ADO.Net connection.

Comment: COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE WITH SQL     [ADO NET Destination [195]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.13-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'"tbl_WRK" ("Number", "DDate", "NDate", "EDate"' at line 1

Comment: it will nevertheless use sql to communicate with the sql database. there has to be a statement in the produced script

Comment: you need to replace the double quotes with the back quote '`' in the sql, where table names, columns, databases are quoted. That syntax is deprecated and is made for an older version of mysql server, mysql 5.6 uses the back quote. Alternatively, change the driver, might solve it

Comment: Oh thank you AdrianBR, But i dont see any option to edit the sql in "ADO.Net Destination Editor".  Can you please, guide me where to edit the sql

Comment: never used it, but would assume that as with any other suite it produces a script that you would save and schedule? opening the script in a text editor should do it unless it's compiled

Comment: It is generating the script in complied time

Comment: I am trying to upgrade my drivers from 5.2.6.  But those are the latest ODBC drivers for MySQL itseems

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not an ADO.NET database. You need to use an OleDB connection (or ODBC, I forget which).

Comment: No MySQL is ADO.NET connection. which is ODBC

Comment: My point is that that is why you are getting the error. ADO.NET connections in SSIS should only be used for SQL Server dbs. For MySQL use an ODBC connection. (and ADO.NET doesn't use ODBC.)

Comment: OLE DB is for SQL SERVER. ADO.NET uses ODBC connection itself. for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719762(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It can connect to an ODBC database, but I never got it to work properly with e.g. Oracle. We always used OleDB connections for non-SQL Server databases and they worked fine.

Comment: I am not sure how you created the OLEDB connection for MySQL.  When I am trying to create a Data source of type OLEDB for MySQL. I don't see option to choose the provider --MySQL

Comment: I was using Oracle. It sounds like you don't have a driver for MySQL on your machine? Or are you using a DSN?

Comment: Here you go: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/03/03/connecting-to-mysql-from-ssis.aspx - and he says use ADO.NET so I apologise, but it soulds like there are quirks to it.

Comment: And from the comments http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2009/01/07/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis.aspx

Comment: np Thank you simon.  I am try to upgrade my system DSN of Mysql 5.2 to 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute this SQL script on the ODBC database to ignore double quotes which is causing the problem:

```
set @@global.sql_mode ='ANSI';
```