# Failing to Import a CSV file into MySQL in SSIS

Tags: mysql, csv, ssis

I am trying to import data from a csv file into a table on a MySQL DB through SSIS. I am using an ADO.NET Destination connection. However, when i run the package i am getting the following error:

```
[ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.5.4-MariaDB]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"fname", "lname", "age", "number") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

I researched and found a similar problem posted here

[Error in SSIS package while importing data from text file into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976745/error-in-ssis-package-while-importing-data-from-text-file-into-mysql)

I then implemented a solution which is found on this link

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/writing-to-a-mysql-database-from-ssis/ba-p/387560

However, i am still getting the error hence this post. Any other solutions out there?

Comment: It would help if you provided more details. Can you share the code where this occurs?

Comment: I haven't written any code. Just developed a data flow consisting of a Flat file Source  and an ADO.Net destination then mapped the source to destination columns